# Can the first argument of Laravel updateOrInsert be used as OR instead of pair the values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

From Laravel Docs:

*The updateOrInsert method will attempt to locate a matching database record using the first argument's column and value pairs.*

```
DB::table('users')
->updateOrInsert(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John'],
    ['votes' => '2']
);
```

Would it be possible instead of checking both records to be true at the same time such as `'email' => 'john@example.com'` and `'name' => 'John'` we check only one such `'email' => 'john@example.com'` OR `'name' => 'John'`

Something like this which is not possible (or i don't know how)

```
 DB::table('users')
->updateOrInsert(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com','OR', 'name' => 'John'],
    ['votes' => '2']
);
```

Is this something that can be done some how?

Comment: Accordingly to the code, you can't an OR in that case: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2924

Comment: No, you cant. you need to make 2 query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short aswer: no

Accordingly to the [code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2924), there's only one `where`, which is expecting an array of attributes, so you can't do an OR clause here.